# Make normal textbox behave like InputBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, wpf-controls

I'm using Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop and i want to make an application that puts several questions one by one in a multi-line textbox and have them answered by the user. So i made a multiline textbox with a single-line textbox under it (like a chatclient)

I would like the single-line textbox to behave like the inputbox function (but without the popup)

To be more specific; i want to write a function that clears the single-line textbox in my program, waits for the user to enter his text and hit return, and then returns the entered text back to the calling code, so i can process the input and move on.

So far i haven't been able to get it right in either VB or C# and a solution in either vb or c# would be welcome :) If i could put it into a usercontrol that can be reused, that would be even better.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to post code here to get useful answers. Try adding some code to the input textbox's KeyDown checking `e.KeyCode`  for return, use the event to .AppendText() to the target multi-line textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a code yet but i created a (silly) samplecode to show what i want to do.

In the mainwindow i made a startbutton, a big multiline textbox named OutputText and a single line textbox named InputText. The outputText will show my text to the user while the InputText should handle the answers a user gives.

When i use InputBox it works like this:

```
    Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    Dim MyFirstName As String
    Dim MyLastName As String
    OutputText.Text = ""
    OutputText.AppendText("What is your first name?" + vbCrLf)
    MyFirstName = InputBox("")
    OutputText.AppendText("And what is your last name?" + vbCrLf)
    MyLastName = InputBox("")
    OutputText.AppendText("Hello " + MyFirstName + " " + MyLastName + "!" + vbCrLf)

End Sub
```

Now i want to do the same thing using my own textbox instead of that annoying popup InputBox and so far i dont have a clue except that i probably have to make my own function to make it work.
I hope the above explains my question a bit better.